# Comparing 2 tables for new or updated rows using composite keys

Tags: t-sql, join, composite-key

I'm writing tsql for SQL Server 2008.  I've got two tables with roughly 2 million rows each.  The Source table gets updated daily and changes are pushed to the Destination table based on a last_edit date.  If this date is newer in source than destination then update the destination row.  If a new row exists in source compared to destination insert it into destination.  This is really only a one way process that I'm concerned with, from source to destination.  The source and destination table use a unique identifier across 4 columns, serialid, itemid, systemcode, and role.

My table are modeled similar to the script below.  There are many data columns but I've limited it to 3 in this example.  I'm looking for 2 outputs.  1 set of data with rows to update and 1 set of data with rows to add.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_DEST](
  [SERIALID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [ITEMID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [SYSTEMCODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [ROLE] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [LAST_EDIT] [datetime] NOT NULL],
  [DATA_COLUMN_1] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [DATA_COLUMN_2] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
  [DATA_COLUMN_3] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_SOURCE](
 [SERIALID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [ITEMID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [SYSTEMCODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [ROLE] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [LAST_EDIT] [datetime] NOT NULL],
 [DATA_COLUMN_1] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [DATA_COLUMN_2] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [DATA_COLUMN_3] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL
)
```

Here's what I've got for the update dataset.

```
select s.*
from table_dest (nolock) inner join table_source s (nolock) 
  on s.SYSTEMCODE = fd.SYSTEMCODE1Y
    and s.ROLE = d.ROLE
    and s.SERIALID = d.SERIALID
    and s.ITEMID = d.ITEMID
    and s.LAST_EDIT > d.LAST_EDIT
```

I don't know how best to accomplish finding the rows to add.  But the solution has to be pretty efficient for the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmatched rows can be found with left/right join and checking target table keys for null:

```
select s.*, case when d.key1 is null then 'insert' else 'update' end [action]
from [table_dest] d right join [table_source] s on (d.key1 = s.key1 /* etc.. */)
```

If you need these rows just to perform respective operations then there is special feature for you:

```
merge [table_dest] d
using [table_source] s on (d.key1 = s.key1 /* etc.. */)
when mathed then
   update set d.a = s.a
when not matched by target then
   insert (key1, .., a) values (s.key1, ..., s.a);
```

Comment: My final solution was to create a processing table with an insert and update column and necessary source data.

    `select case when s.SYSTEMCODE is null then 'insert' else 'update' end [action], 0 is_processed, s.*
    into to_process
    from table_dest right join table_source on 
      ( s.key1 = d.key1 .... )`